# I want my sphere to decrease the health of my player when my sphere is near my player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthBarScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Image HealthBar;
  public float CurrentHealth;
  public float MaxHealth = 100f;
  int Damage = 10;
  PlayerController_Script Player;

  private void Start()
  {
    HealthBar = GetComponent<Image>();
    CurrentHealth = 100f;
  }
  public void TakeDamage(int Damage)
  {
    CurrentHealth -= Damage;
    HealthBar.fillAmount = CurrentHealth/MaxHealth;
  }
}
```

HealthBarScript: this is the script for my health bar UI. The health bar is a knob image with a filled image type. The method TakeDamage is supposed to be called whenever the 2nd script (AddDamage) calls it. Once the damage is taken, the health bar is supposed to decrease by 10, changing the amount filled in the filled image. This script is attached to the Image HealthBar.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AddDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float radius = 3;
  public int Damage = 10;
  public GameObject FPSController;
  public HealthBarScript HealthBarScript;

  void Start()
  {
  }

  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
  {
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
    foreach(Collider FPSController in colliders);
    {
      if(FPSController.tag == "Player");
      {
        HealthBarScript.TakeDamage(Damage);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

AddDamage: This is my collision script for when the collider of the sphere has the FPS controller within its surrounding radius, (The FPS controller is tagged Player), it will see the tag of the FPScontroller and call the TakeDamage method of the HealthBarScript. This script is attached to the Game Object sphere.

The issue I am currently having is that although the health bar is supposed to decrease by 10 whenever the surrounding radius of the sphere has the FPS controller within it (AddDamage calls the TakeDamage method within the HealthBarScript whenever the FPS controller is within the collider array), nothing happens. There are no errors on the console.

Comment: Please don't post your code as images.

Comment: Thank you, I hope this is better formatted

Answer (score 0):

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
  {
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
    foreach(Collider FPSController in colliders);
    {
      if(FPSController.tag == "Player");
      {
        HealthBarScript.TakeDamage(Damage);
      }
    }
  }
```

If I understand that method correctly:

1. Wait for 3D Collision (not trigger) on that object
2. Get all 3D colliders at that position
3. Check every collider, if it has the "Player" tag
4. Make the Healthbar-Script take damage

You are waiting for collisions and then you check with the raycast. If you don't want that, put the raycasting stuff into a (fixed)update method

Comment: why does it need to be checked with the raycast? doesn't the `if(FPSController.tag == "Player");` line already look into the colliders array and checks if one of them is the player?

Comment: I just copied the lines you wrote. Again I am not sure, but I guess you'd rather put that code into an update method or something, because it ONLY checks for collision, on the first frame it collides with the SOLID 3D collider. I am not sure if this is really intended. The rest of the code is fine, but that collision method throws me off. Maybe you can upload an unlisted video to youtube showing what is not working and the intended behaviour